# anchor tag not working

Tags: html

I am trying to create an anchor tag but its not working in any of the browsers
I am going from one page to another

```
<p>
  <a href="/oneprogram/default.aspx#Code2011">View All Code Related Issues</a>
</p>
```

and its going to this page having 10-12 anchor tags..

```
<div class="grouping">
  <h4 id="Code2011">
    <a>Code 2011</a>
  </h4>
</div>
```

I tried these too:

```
<div class="grouping">
  <h4 id="Code2011">
    <a id="Code2011">Code 2011</a>
  </h4>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="grouping">
  <h4>
    <a name="Code2011">Code 2011</a>
  </h4>
</div>
```

but none of them are working: When I go to that page and press enter on the url it then works...so that means my url is coming up fine...any ideas?

Comment: The last one should work, it will look for `<a>` with such name. Can you post link to the website?

Comment: The attribute "name" is deprecated in HTML for anchors. I don't see any reason why the first method shouldn't work, although I am curious why you have an anchor tag with no attributes

Comment: yah I read that that's why i started using id but thats also not working...i was using a tag just to make anchor tag work then I saw i can use it with h4 or may be with div also ...I tried removing <a> tag around Code 2011 but still result is same...It goes to that h4 and then comes back to original position and when I hit enter it works...sorry its internal site...u would not be able to see it..

Comment: Is it possible that you have several tags with same ID?

Comment: No, these are unique and there is no other tag with the same ID....

Answer (score 2):

I found that this works better.  Don't know why.

```
<div class="grouping">
  <h4>
    <a name="Code2011"></a>
    Code 2011
  </h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found that sometimes you can mistakenly have another element with the same ID.  In my case, it was an option tag, which cannot be moved into view.  As such, I would recommend you try `$('#yourid')` to see if there are any tags unexpectedly with the same ID.

Answer (score 1):

In general:

- 'name' is deprecated, so don't use it.
- All id's must be unique, no exceptions. You cannot have duplicated
  id's.
- Anchor id's need to occur in anchor tags. So something like `<h4
  id="myanchor">` wouldn't work as an anchor.

Your second example would work for you if you removed (or rename) the id from the H4 tag.

Answer (score 0):

For others future reference, I've noticed anchors not working well within some divs.  They seem to work better when placed next to a recognizable page element like an image or a table row, something on the page that isn't buried within a div.  I think what may happen is with floated elements and relative positioning the page can't find the precise spot of your anchor so you get nothing.

Try:
     
    
    Code 2011